# Use multiple database in .net core

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

I want to use multiple databases in my application and the connection should depend on the users input when calling the api, I am using .net core 3.1 and postgresql. Is it possible to use a single db context and change the connection string on run time?

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionString can be changed in OnConfiguring method of DbContext as below:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    //get connectionString 
    var connString = _connectionStringService.GetConnectionString(); 

    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString);//or whatever 
}
```

And also, in order to fetch custom connectionString, you can have some service injected to be used in OnConfiguring method:

```
public MyDbContext(IConnectionStringService connectionStringService) 
      : base(options)
{
    _connectionStringService = connectionStringService) ;
}
```